# What is the difference between sed and awk regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have one awk and one sed example. Both seems to be using the same regular expression, but the output differs. So the pattern expansion must be getting different. But i can not get the difference. Can anyone explain?

```
 $ echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" |sed -e 's/[^ ]*(H|F)[^ ]*/<red>&/g'
THE BEAR ATE THE FISH
 $ echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" | awk 'gsub(/[^ ]*(H|F)[^ ]*/,"<red>&")'
<red>THE BEAR ATE <red>THE <red>FISH
 $ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5
 $ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
```

Comment: Seems in sed, instead of `(H|F)`, `[HF]` does give same output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using alternation `|` in your regexp which is part of the extended regexp class.  The difference is with `sed`  *(and `grep`)* you need to be explicit when you want to use extended regexp by giving the `-r` flag with `GNU sed` and the `-E` with `GNU grep`:

```
$ echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" | sed -re 's/[^ ]*(H|F)[^ ]*/<red>&/g'
<red>THE BEAR ATE <red>THE <red>FISH
```

Alternately you can escaped the extended regexp features:

```
$ echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" |sed -e 's/[^ ]*\(H\|F\)[^ ]*/<red>&/g'
<red>THE BEAR ATE <red>THE <red>FISH
```

Better yet you could use a character class here:

```
$ echo "THE BEAR ATE THE FISH" |sed 's/[^ ]*[HF][^ ]*/<red>&/g'
<red>THE BEAR ATE <red>THE <red>FISH
```

The manual pages for all three tools have sections explaining there use with regular expressions.